# Is there a way to get the contnents of an RPG program using SQL?

Tags: db2, metadata, db2-midrange

So, I've got myself a query to list our RPG programs:

```
SELECT OBJNAME
FROM
    (SELECT OBJNAME AS SCHEMA FROM TABLE (QSYS2.OBJECT_STATISTICS('*ALLSIMPLE', 'LIB')) S) AS SCHEMAS
    ,LATERAL (SELECT * FROM TABLE(QSYS2.OBJECT_STATISTICS(SCHEMAS.SCHEMA, 'PGM')) X) AS PROGRAMS
    LEFT JOIN QSYS2.PROCEDURES
        ON QSYS2.PROCEDURES.PROCNAME = PROGRAMS.OBJNAME
        AND QSYS2.PROCEDURES.PROCSCHEMA = PROGRAMS.OBJLONGSCHEMA
WHERE
    PROCNAME IS NULL
    AND SCHEMAS.SCHEMA = 'MYLIB'
;
```

Now, is there any way, given the name of an RPG program, to get the contents of it via SQL?

(Or, failing SQL, some other way to get the contents from within a C# application?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "contents"...

At v7.3 and more at v7.4 IBM has added some services for program info, module info, ect...
[IBM i Services (SQL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1119123)

But if you're thinking "contents" as in a source list...

Then you'd have needed to have the program compiled with DBGVIEW(*LIST|*COPY|*ALL) and then use the [debugger APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/debug1.htm) to retrieve the source...